# Grub menu has vanished

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Both Windows and Ubuntu are installed on my computer(a Dell Inspiron laptop). Windows came pre-installed, and I installed Ubuntu myself.

Both worked fine until today, when I turned off the laptop after a bit of browsing. Until then everything worked fine. When I powered the machine back on today, a black screen showed 'No bootable device found'. The grub menu has completely vanished, along with Ubuntu. I played some time with boot settings and finally loaded default factory settings.

Now it just boot into Windows, not even a sign of Ubuntu. I tried to repair grub [by following this guide](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)but it returned 'EFI device could not be found'. Can someone help me? Any help would be appreciated. Please excuse my English.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: "finally loaded default factory settings" sounds like you probably restored the machine's factory-default configuration from the recovery partition, which likely erased your Ubuntu installation. :(